# My .Net 5 console application is not loading the Dependencies Packages and Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net 5 console application and it is working well inside my windows server 2012 R2 + Visual Studio 2019. now I copied the console application to my Windows 10 PC which also have Visual Studio 2019 >> but when i open the project inside my Windows 10 PC, i got that the Dependencies Packages and Assemblies  are not loading, as follow:-

[image]

and when I run the project I got this message:-

[image]

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. The error message complains that you tried to debug using .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.

Comment: The .NET Runtime contains just the components needed to run a console app. Typically, you'd also install the ASP.NET Core Runtime, refer [Download .NET 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0). Please check your windows machine, make sure it has installed the Asp.net 5 SDK and Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You must install .Net 5.0 Separately. It's not automatic installed with VS2019 or Win10.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet